# How to parse chinese charecters using sax parser in IOS

Tags: ios, saxparser

I am facing problem with parsing chinese characters in my application. i am having few url which contains chinese characters. those url are used to download images. url are part of response i am getting from server, and response is in xml format. i need to parse response and get each url in response and download image. if url contains english characters i am able to fetch entire url and i am downloading successfully, if url contains chinese characters then parser's parseErrorOccurred delegate method is called. when i print that url in foundcharacter
method, that url is getting splited in to 2 half, some thing like this.
"http://somewebsite.com/folder1/folder2" (first half), ㅊㅎㅅㄱ대ㅐㅐㄱㅆㅅㅉ/Image/Medium/10082013052045560.jpg (second half).

why it is happening like this? any idea? 
thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using `NSXMLParser`? If yes, you need to change the encoding.

Comment: Yes i am using NSXMLParser.. i am encoding as NSUTF8StringEncoding. is it right?

Comment: but i am facing same problem.. not able to resolve it..